# Angular Render Image tag in NG repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have the HTML below and I am trying to get the Image tag in the field item.Image to render. Does any Angular gurus know why the below doesn't work?

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in results.results" >

 <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="item.Image"></div> <!-- item.Image is <a href="image/test.png"/> -->
```

Comment: Well for one, an anchor tag is not self closing.

Comment: Have you included `ngSanitize`?  Also depending on what version of Angular you are using it can be `ng-bind-html-unsafe` or `ng-bind-html` not sure what version of Angular was when the switch was made to the latter, I think around 1.1.4 perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be due to which version of angular you are using.

`ngBindHtmlUnsafe` was replaced with `ngBindHtml` in 1.2

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#ngbindhtmlunsafe-has-been-removed-and-replaced-by-ngbindhtml

[Here is a working example with 1.07](http://jsbin.com/kehowogu/1/edit?html,js,output) using `ngBindHtmlUnsafe`

[And here is a working example with 1.2](http://jsbin.com/hilonemo/1/edit?html,js,output) using `ngBindHtml`(Note that ng-sanitize needs to be passed in as a dependency)